# How to write the following Query in SQL

Tags: sql

How to write the Query for:

If I have a Table like Employee. Suppose I have n rows, I want to leave top+2 rows and display from n/2+3 rows, e'g 10 rows,then display from 8th rows

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.  How are we supposed to understand "then display from 8th rows"?  Is there more than one 8th row?

Comment: Rows in a table of a relational database are **not** sorted, so there is no such thing as the 8th row - unless you have some column that you can use to sort them (using `order by`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, It could help:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 2 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT (SELECTCOUNT(1)/2 + 3 from Employee) ROWS ONLY
```

If MySQL, try using LIMIT like @O_Z stated.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is standard SQL:

```
select *
from (
  select e.*, 
         row_number() over (order by some_column) as rn, 
         count(*) over () as total_rows
  from employee
) t
where rn in (1,2) 
   or rn >= (total_rows/2) + 3
   or rn > 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql ,if you need different limit ranges on the same query
Use union for example:

```
select myCol from mytab limit 2,3
uniion 
select myCol from mytab  limit 10,40
union 
.....
```

Comment: What about FROM clause? On the other hand, are you assuming that this is MySQL?

Comment: @LuisTeijon thought U get the idea, however I will fix.No need to down vote

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
EXCEPT(
    SELECT TOP 2 *
    FROM Employee
)
```